# Javascript regex to find quotes in text not preceded by brackets and not followed by brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

**Background**

I need to replace the simple quotes by double quotes but only which ones are not before opening and closing brackets. I develop a node script to convert java i18n properties files to Excel files that are more easier to use for a translator. The script can convert the properties files to xlsx files and then convert the xlsx files to properties files. The quotes have to be doubled in the java project resources (regarding the MessageSource documentation) but I don't want to ask to the translators to double them directly in the Excel sheet.

**Problem**

I have some difficulties to create a javascript regex to find simple quotes that are NOT preceded by brackets AND that are NOT followed by brackets.

For example, I have this text :

> The John's car has '{value}' wheels.

The regex should only return the first quote but not the two following quotes.

I need this regex in Javascript and the problem is that I cannot use "lookbehind" operator because it's not supported.

I tried this:

```
(?!\})'(?!\{)
```

But it continues to capture the " }' ".

Comment: Can you show us your code and attempts?

Comment: And what do you want to do with that lonely ' ?

Comment: I guess [`\b'\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Xn1Ijh/1) will work if the goal is to match a `'` that is enclosed with word chars.

Comment: Else, what are you doing? What do you need to do with these single quotes? Remove? Replace? Do you need to also match `'` in `12'`? Do you want to specifically avoid touching `'` just around `{...}` substrings?

Comment: I need to replace the simple quotes by double quotes but only which ones are not before opening and closing brackets.

I develop a node script to convert java i18n properties files to Excel files that are more easier to use for a translator. The script can convert the properties files to xlsx files and then convert the xlsx files to properties files.

The quotes have to be doubled in the java project resources (regarding the MessageSource documentation) but I don't want to ask to the translators to double them directly in the Excel sheet. So my script will do the job ;)

Comment: @bdkopen : I tried this : (?!\})'(?!\{)
But it continues to capture the " }' "

Comment: It is still not clear, try [`.replace(/('{[^{}]*}')|'/g, function($0,$1) { return $1?$1:'"';})`](https://jsfiddle.net/4Ldaa9wa/)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just need to match any substring starting with `'{`, then having any chars other than braces and ending with `}'` and skip these matches, and match `'` in any other context to replace with `"`.

Use a callback inside `replace` like this

```js
var s = "The John's car '  has '{value}' wheels.";
s = s.replace(/('{[^{}]*}')|'/g, function($0,$1) { return $1?$1:'"';});
console.log(s);
```

**Details**

- `('{[^{}]*}')` - Group 1 (referenced with `$1` inside the callback): a `'{...}'` substring:

  - `'{` - a `'{` substring
  - `[^{}]*` - any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`
  - `}'` - a `}'` substring
- `|` - or
- `'` - a single quote in any other context

Inside the callback, the `$0` is a variable holding the whole match and `$1` references the value captured into Group 1.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
[^{}]'[^{}]|[^{}]'$|^'[^{}]
```

[test](https://regex101.com/r/Y0MK3e/2)

Answer (score 0):

If your example is relevant, you cold do it with

```
\b'\b
```

```js
var str = "The John's car has '{value}' wheels.";

document.write("Should only be one: " + str.match(/\b'\b/g));
document.write("<br/>Should be all: " + str.match(/'/g));
```

It uses `\b` (matches word boundary) to make it match only `'` bordering word characters.

[Better illustrated here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3NyrHX/1).

Comment: I need too the quotes that are preceded by space or followed by space.

So if I have the text : 
> The John ' s car has '{value}' wheels.

I need to have the same result.